# Determine whether the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are parallel, skew, or intersecting. If they intersect, find the point of intersection.

Tags: vectors

> Determine whether the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are parallel, skew, or intersecting. If they intersect, find the point of intersection.
>   $$L_1:\frac{x-2}1=\frac{y-3}{-2}=\frac{z-1}{-3}$$
>   $$L_2:\frac{x-3}1=\frac{y+4}3=\frac{z-2}{-7}$$

I was showed an example of the lines in $s$ and $t$ form but now they are in this form, so I'm not sure what to do now. I looked online and couldn't find an example anywhere. I could probably convert it to $s$ and $t$ form but I'm not sure how and if I tried it would probably be the wrong way to do it anyway. If anyone could please help me I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equate both lines' equations to parameters $t,u$:
$$\frac{x-2}1=\frac{y-3}{-2}=\frac{z-1}{-3}=t$$
$$\frac{x-3}1=\frac{y+4}3=\frac{z-2}{-7}=u$$
Thus
$$L_1=(2,3,1)+t(1,-2,-3)$$
$$L_2=(3,-4,2)+u(1,3,-7)$$
Since $(2,3,1)$ is not a scalar multiple of $(3,-4,2)$, the lines are not parallel. To see if they intersect, equate the first two coordinates and solve for $t,u$:
$$t+2=u+3\implies t-u=1$$
$$-2t+3=3u-4\implies 2t+3u=7$$
from which we get $t=2,u=1$. Now substitute into the equation for the third coordinate:
$$-3(2)+1=-5=-7(1)+2$$
So the two lines intersect, and their point of intersection is $(4,-1,-5)$.